# Let $S=\{1,2,3,\ldots, 2n\}.$ If $P\subseteq S$ such that $x,y\in P \rightarrow x\nmid y$ and $y \nmid x$ then what is the maximum cardinality of $P$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, pigeonhole-principle

Let $S=\{1,2,3,\ldots, 2n\}.$ If $P\subseteq S$ such that if $x,y\in P \rightarrow x\nmid y$ and $y \nmid x$ Then what is the maximum cardinality of $P$

I know that $\{n+1, n+2,\ldots, 2n\}\subseteq P$ so $|P|\geq n$

How can I proceed from here. I somehow want to use Pigeonhole principle.

Comment: $n\mid 2n$, so your $P$ doesn't work. However, if you remove $n$ from your $P$, you still have $n$ elements.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315050/using-pigeonhole-principle-to-prove-two-numbers-in-a-subset-of-2n-divide-eac) is sort of a duplicate. I'm still looking for a better match, though with what you have (after Arthur's correction) that answers your question.

Comment: [A different approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493253/prove-using-induction-that-from-a-set-of-n1-numbers-from-1-2-2n-at-l); sort of pigeon hole, [with guidance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065784/deducing-divisibility-based-on-pigeonhole-principle).

Comment: "*I know that $\{n,n+1,\dots,2n\}\subseteq P$*"  Not necessarily.  Consider $n=2$ so $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$.  There are two examples of subsets of maximum cardinality each of which satisfying the desired property, namely $\{2,3\}$ and $\{3,4\}$.  It is a particularly strong claim, one that requires proof, to say that $\{n+1,n+2,\dots,2n\}$ has the maximum cardinality of such a set.  Certainly, you could show that it is maxi**mal** in the sense that you couldn't add any more to it, but what makes it so that a set like $\{2,3,5,7,\dots\}$ wouldn't have more elements than $\{n+1,n+2,\dots,2n\}$?

Comment: sorry I meant $\{n+1,n+2\ldots 2n\}$